# PDFs in a FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, printing, flowdocument

I have a FlowDocument which is created dynamically (containing several tables). I need to embed PDF documents in this document. Eg: I might have a table, then a couple of PDF documents, then another table.

What's the best way to go about this. At worst I could print all of the PDFs, then all of the tables but I really need to keep each set of documents/PDFs together.

Comment: How exactly are you going to "print all of the PDFs"?

Comment: hi, ijust want to know yhat if you find the solution for your problem. As m too in the same situation. Want to print pdfs in flowdocuments.

Answer (score 0):

You can create common container width list of printable elements.
Printable element is flow document width table or pdf document.
And after that you can make method like that

```
void Print() {
    foreach(IPrintableElement el in _printableElements){ 
       el.Print();
      // where Print() is realization for flow document printing or pdf document printing
    }
}
```

But on this way you tables and PDFs will be printed on different pages.

Comment: But this will really just print each one sequentially. I wanted to embed them all into one big document. I'll probably end up choosing MigraDoc - http://www.pdfsharp.net/MigraDocOverview.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1